How to change JQuery terminal cursor when it is not in focus?
Ive been trying to see how I can change the cursor of jquery terminal when the page is not in focus. By default, it seems that when you click off the page making it unfocused, the cursor will dissappear. How can I make it so that it can just turn into an "empty box" like in most terminals? I took a look at the documentation found here: Documentation and I think I have to use the onBlur and onFocus functions to change it but im not sure how to use it.
Would some css similar to this help me achive it?:
.cmd:not(:focus) {
/* change the css of the cursor */
}

I tried taking a look at a few online articles about changing a css element when its not in focus, but I havent been able to find something that does what im asking. Im also not exactly sure how to change the Jquery terminal's cursor specs like width, height, rotation, etc.
Example of cursor I want when not in focus:


And If you want to edit the look of the cursor, you need to look at the animation inside the source code. There are few examples (builtin animations), but if you don't know how to create a particular animation, you can ask another question. You will get a better answer if you describe an example what you want. Also, better documentation is not a Wiki.

@Invulner is correct here is a working example:


$('body').terminal();
.cmd:not(:focus-within) .cmd-cursor {
    outline: 1px solid var(--color, #ccc);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.terminal/js/jquery.terminal.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.terminal/css/jquery.terminal.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



NOTE: I wanted to edit his answer, but it felt weird.

I'd just edit his answer to include the snippet. What feels weirder; editing his answer, or receiving the rep for his answer?

You can use :focus-within pseudo-class:
/* Style for cursor when terminal is focused */
.cmd:focus-within .cmd-cursor {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Style for cursor when terminal is not focused */
.cmd:not(:focus-within) .cmd-cursor {
  background-color: green;
}

With these selectors, you can customize the cursor using any CSS properties you want, such as width, height, background-color and so on.

thanks, but inside it, I tried changing the color first to see if it works, and for some reason, it doesn't work. To change the color in the terminal, the css variable: --color: is used for it, but even with that nothing changes when I go out of focus. I also tried: --animation: to change the cursor type, but still no change.

Here is an example with a different background color of the cursor, which depends on the focus state as I suggested. It's forked from the official CodePen example from the documentation. I just added a short example at the bottom, starting from line 248.

thanks but could you put the example here? I only work on a school computer and sites like jsfiddle, playcode and codepen are blocked for me. Sorry for the inconvenience, but thanks for helping me.

I've put it into the answer. Still the same selectors, just added the background-color property.
